# How to create an array with unique "character names"?

Tags: arrays, swift, unique

I hope you can help me a bit with this:

```
var characters1 = [Character]()

  func selectCharacterScreen1() {
    var name: String = ""
    var error: Bool = false

    repeat {
        if error == true {
            print("Please type a valid character's name. His name must be unique.")
        }
        else {
            print("Please type an unique character's name")
        }
        name = inputString()
        error = false
        for c in characters1 {
            if  c.nameCharacter == name {
                error = false
                break
            }
        }
    } while error == true
}
```

I expect that the code has to check if the character's names are all unique or not. If not, the code has to refuse and the user must retype an another character's name. In this code, you can type the character's name but the code doesn't care if it's the character's name is unique or not.

Comment: Unrelated, but you shouldn't create a class that has the same name as an existing class.

Comment: thanks for the advice

Comment: There isn't really a question here. What does the code do, and what did you expect it to do? I can see a comment hiding "it doesn't work as expected" (readers rarely spot these) but even so, this is not clear. What did you expect?

Comment: Worth a read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: The player has to pick 3 characters for his team. But before that, he has to type unique character's name for each characters picked. I expect that the code has to check if there are 3 unique character's names. Else he has to propose to the player to retype the name character. But in this current form, this code doesn't check if it's unique or not. Sorry my post is not clear. It's my first time here.

Comment: Your code uses error == false to mean two different things — that the name is good and that the name isn’t unique.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the list should contain strings, not Characters, and secondly, Your code is very unclear around here:

```
repeat {
        if error == true {
            print("Please type a valid character's name. His name must be unique.")
        }
        else {
            print("Please type an unique character's name")
        }
        name = inputString()
        error = false
        for c in characters1 {
            if  c.nameCharacter == name {
                error = false
                break
            }
        }
} while error == true
```

You have a fundemental flaw in the idea of error = false (in the for loop). If a name matches as non-unique, it should set error to true.

If you are only looking to input one name and check if that name is already in the Characters1 list, then change the for loop to read like this:

```
for c in characters1 {
    if  c == name {
        error = true # it has to set error to true so the for loop rejects the name and restarts
        break
    }
}
if error == false {
    characters1.append(name)
}
```

This code should work for one player. If you want to input, say, 3 names, put the whole repeat loop in a for loop, to look like this:

```
var characters1 = [String]()

func selectCharacterScreen1() {
    var name: String = ""
    var error: Bool = false

    for x in 1...3{
        repeat {
            if error == true {
                print("Please type a valid character's name. His name must be unique.")
            }
            else {
                print("Please type an unique character's name")
            }
            name = inputString
            error = false
            for c in characters1 {
                if  c == name {
                    error = true
                    break
                }
            }
            if error == false {
                characters1.append(name)
            }
        } while error == true
    }
}
```

I tried this and it worked for me. Please tell me if you don't understand

Comment: Ok I will try your code, thanks a lot. I will tell you if it's working :)

Comment: ok I tried it and i get an error from xcode at the 'else': Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Character'

Comment: Can I do it with the 'contains' function from an array?

Comment: ok thanks a lot, I will try it and give you some feedback asap.